# iOS App Different Timezone treating Date Entries Different

Tags: ios, date, core-data, timezone, nspredicate

I have released my first app to the App Store 2 months ago and the success has been excellent thus far. I have recently however discovered an issue.

The premise of the app is to be able to keep track of money envelopes given and received. It's a simple app that allows you to add entries and then in the tab bar, it displays the chronological timeline, followed by filtering just by the Name, Event and Year in the other tabs. It works well around the world, except for when you change the timezone.

The app uses core data in the background including some `NSPredicate` checks to see "if this year that you're selecting already exists, I will return it and if it does not, I will create a new entry for the year". So if you have one entry with 2014 and one with 2013 as the years, in the Year tab, you will see one entry for 2014 and one for 2013. If you add another entry for 2014, you will not see two 2014 entries in the year tab, but still a single 2014 entry (with all of the transactions below).

The date is selected using a `UIDatePicker` to obtain the actual date.

The problem arises when you change timezones. If you do this, an entry with 2014 as the year no longer gets recognised as the same entry as a previous 2014 and so in the year tab, I'm ending up with multiple 2014 entries which of course makes no sense.

I figured out this was related to timing and below you can see I'm not using timezones, but rather using the `NSGregorianCalendar` functionality.

```
NSCalendar *yearCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponent = [yearCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
NSDate *selectedYear = [yearCal dateFromComponents:yearComponent];
```

Without changing the functionality too much here of the app (I want it to work in the same way), how would I go about specifying a timezone of say GMT but because of daylight savings, etc, I'd want to keep it to something like 12pm GMT as a standard, so no matter where you are in the world, it'll focus on 12pm GMT for the time.

I hope this makes sense but any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: usually I am using dateFormatter with GMT timezone to parse date strings, and sending/recieving date string with zero timezone (e.g @"01/01/2014 +000"). `NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormater new]; [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: 0]]`. Not sure is that correct solution, but it working fine for my needs

Comment: Dear Mykola - many thanks for the reply and that made sense - I used the answer from Martin to get this working but I do understand your approach as well - appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time zones are pretty tricky to deal with.. you always have to consider the semantics of your date property (e.g. if a value entered in 2014 in australia should show up as 'in 2014' or 'in 2013' because the 'home timezone' is in the US where it was 2013 and so on)

NSCalendar defaults to use the current local timezone, as does UIDatePicker (and NSTimeFormatter, which is used internally when you do `po date` in the debugger).
My first advice is to store the year as a separate field in the DB if you want to do filtering based on it..

But if you want to 'normalize' date values to a specific time zone you can set the UTC timezone on `NSDateComponents` to get the first moment of the year in UTC:

```
NSCalendar *yearCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponent = [yearCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[yearComponent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]
NSDate *selectedYear = [yearCal dateFromComponents:yearComponent];
```

This overrides `NSCalendar`'s own timeZone property (which should be the same as UIDatePicker's).

Comment: Hi Martin - many thanks for the reply and my apologies for the late reply (been a bit of a crazy few days) but your code really helped massively and ensured this bug has now been removed. That was really helpful and it makes complete sense with using the UTC timezone. Many thanks for that - highly appreciated!